# Переадресация с одного языка на другой

Tags: wordpress

Использую плагин qTranslate для многоязычного сайта на Wordpress.
Допустим есть запись на одном языке (английском), но если выбрать русский язык, то он сообщит, что есть версия только на английском. Можно сделать так, чтобы была переадресация на доступный язык или просто выдавало 404 ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У qTranslate механизм мультиязычности основан на шорткодах. Фактически в одном посте пишутся контент на всех языках.
Те по факту 404 быть не может.

Иной механизм у Polylang - каждый язык в отдельных постах. Т.е. можно и 404.

*Про 301 ничего не подскажу.*

Comment: На Ваш взгляд какой из этих плагинов лучше?

Comment: Зависит от задач.

Comment: Задача сделать сайт на двух языках.

Comment: Это не задача, а цель :) Задач у сайта может быть много. В тч и касаемо бекэнда. Вот у вас одна из задач - делать не зависимые друг от друга записи. Для этого Polylang подойдёт лучше. Но для других qTranslate может оказаться лучше.

Comment: всё верно, установил Polylang в итоге то что нужно другое там нет. В итоге думаю делать перенаправление с помощью js.

Comment: Вообще вопросы по конкретным плагинам стоит задавать на их оф. форумах. Наверняка есть правильные решения. js - это какой-то костыль.

Comment: единственный ответ который я нашёл от разработчиков - это помогите нам донатом мы будем развивать проект. Причём многие подобный вопрос задают, решения так и нет. Есть решения это переадресация на уровне php, но он криво работает.

Comment: Есть ещё платный WPML. Механизм как у полилинга, но больше не знаю.